Company Samsung Galaxy - how to check if I have proxy or VPN enabled?
I have the company owned Samsung Galaxy. I probably have MDM software on my phone - I see I have Knox 3.3 version, TIMA 3.3.0 and there apps: "Knox Analytics Uploader, "Knox Enrollment Service", "KnoxVpnPacProcessor", "Enterprise Sim Pin Service", WlanTest, "MDMapp". It is likely that administrators also use the Intune environment.
From what I've read, MDMs don't have the access to things like downloaded files or internet history unless they connect the user through a VPN or proxy, is this true?
In my case in the phone's settings under connections there's stance "No VPNs". Also there's "none" in proxy connection settings.
My question is, can I be signed up to a corporate proxy or VPN without knowing it (not having the infomation about it in the phone settings I mentioned)?
I would be very grateful for information from people who know about this. Thanks!

Unless the company performs HTTPS inspection using a proxy or a VPN the admins may only see the host names you connect to.  You can check if HTTPS interception is used by comparing the root CA certificate used e.g. by this site on your phone and on a second device that is not managed by your company. Open in Chrome the site info and there connection info. Compare the shown public key data.

Thanks for your reply! Unfortunately, to be honest, I didn't understand much - what I meant was exactly whether the company can use a proxy or VPN in such a way that I don't see it in the settings
also, from what I've read, MDM does not provide access to Host names - based on this for example https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/intune/user-help/what-info-can-your-company-see-when-you-enroll-your-device-in-intune
